# vba printing code in word stopped working

Tags: vba, printing, ms-word

I am having trouble with this printing code as it was working and all of a sudden stopped. I tried using break mode and figured the issue is in the line with PrintOut. without specifying a range it works and prints two full copies of the document.

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Select
Selection.Find.Text = "Instructions"
blnFound = Selection.Find.Execute
endCount = ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
startCount = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
pag1 = startCount & "-" & endCount - 1
pag2 = endCount & "-" & endCount
Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Copies:=2, Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Pages:=pag1
```

Comment: Might have something to do with `wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber` - what value is that returning and is it the value you'd expect? Try the `Information` option without "adjusted" and see if that^s any better. Also try printing manually with the same range of pages values the code is using.